# RoR as_json call missing data that's in the database

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

using rails 4.1.8, ruby 2.2, mysql, elasticsearch-rails 5.0.4, elasticsearch 5.2. the selectors field on the Selector model is stored as json in a varchar column and for some reason when I load a location and its associated selector using as_json, the selectors field comes back nil when I know there is data in the column?

the Selector table:

```
create table Selectors do 
   t.text selectors
   t.text selectors_other
   t.references location
   t.timestamps
end
```

I recently added Elastic Search so the model has:

```
settings index: {
   analysis: {
      analyzer: {
         selector_analyzer: {
            type: :standard,
            stopwords: ["some","words","here"]
         }
      }
   }
}

mapping do
   indexes :selectors, {analyzer: :selector_analyzer}
   indexes :selectors_other, {analyzer: :selector_analyzer}
end

def as_indexed_json(options={})
   {
      'id' => id,
      'selectors' => selectors,
      'selectors_other' => selectors_other
   }
end
```

and the call I make to get the data for the view is

```
Location.find(<id>).as_json(:include => [:selector, :response])
```

every field I expect is in the json and all the data is there except the selectors field which is nil. I know there is data because if I do:

```
loc = Location.find(<id>)
loc.selector
```

the selectors field is not nil. I tried adding an as_json method to the Selector model but it didn't have any effect. The only changes I've made recently were to add the Selector model to the Elasticsearch index. I used an IndexManager in order to create one index with multiple types and created a rake task for deployments and re-indexing. The only distinction is that this field is stored as json, but it was working fine before.

Any ideas, suggestions, etc would be appreciated since I can't think of anything that would cause it to be nil.

Answer (score 0):

figured out what was causing the field to be nil, tho not why it is causing a problem

I had added a method to manipulate the json when updating the selectors field, in that method I had a line like

```
sel_hash = JSON.parse(self.selectors)
```

the IDE was unable to resolve self.selectors so I added

```
attr_accessor :selectors
```

and that line for some reason caused the selectors field to be nil, go figure